# alter sequence to sync to another sequence

Tags: postgresql

I have two sequences :

```
sequence_a
sequence_b
```

they're used to generate primary keys for

```
table_a
table_b
```

I need to restart sequence_b so that it's nextval() will be the same as the nextval() for sequence_a.

I can't seem to do this purely in SQL; everything I tried failed.  No permutations of `ALTER SEQUENCE` would accept a lastval(), currval() wasn't defined for this session , and a few other issues.

Does anyone have a clue how I can do this?  I can do it manually, but this won't work for my needs.  This is part of a database migration, where records from A are being cloned into B.

The sequences will eventually diverge, so it would be acceptable for my needs if sequence_b were a higher number than sequence_a; I just need to ensure that sequence_b starts with some number higher than the highest sequence_a id.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few options here. The easiest is probably to use `setval` instead of `ALTER SEQUENCE`, since you only care about `b` being equal or higher:

```
SELECT setval('sequence_b', nextval('sequence_a'));
```